# Como mantener el color de fondo al cambiarlo

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estoy haciendo un boton dia y noche y quiero que se guarde en una Cookie cuando el usuario cambia de color la pagina asi si el usuario sale de la web el modo oscuro o el modo claro se mantiene

este es mi codigo

```
function dark(){

    document.body.style.background = '#202225';
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('day-main');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "whitesmoke";
  }
  function day(){

    document.body.style.background = '#f1f1f1';
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('day-main');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "black"
  }
```

y el codigo en los botones

```html
<button id='white' onclick='day()'/>
<button id='black' onclick='dark()'/>
```

alguien tiene idea de como lograr que se guarde?

Answer (score 2):

Para guardar el estado del fondo lo puedes hacer con "localStorage":

Lo creas con:

```
miStorage = window.localStorage;
```

Luego para obtener el estado actual usas:

```
var estado = localStorage.getItem('estado');
```

Si el estado es 1 le pones dia y si no noche:

```
if(estado==1)
  day();
else if(estado==0)
  dark();
```

Si no es ninguno de los 2 no pasa nada.

Luego para colocar el estado en cada función usas:

```
localStorage.setItem('estado', 0);
```

y el código te queda así por ejemplo:

```
<body>

    <button id='white' onclick='day()'/>Día</button>
    <button id='black' onclick='dark()'/>Noche</button>
    Hola
    <div id="main-cont"></div>
    <div id="post-title-data"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    miStorage = window.localStorage;

var estado = localStorage.getItem('estado');

if(estado==1)
  day();
else if(estado==0)
  dark();

function dark(){
    localStorage.setItem('estado', 0);
    document.body.style.background = '#202225';
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('day-main');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "whitesmoke";
  }

  function day(){
    localStorage.setItem('estado', 1);
    document.body.style.background = '#f1f1f1';
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('day-main');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "black"
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Al parecer si se crea el ``localStorage`` pero al recargar regresa al color anterior

Answer (score 0):

Se puede resolver de esta manera:

```js
function dark(){
    var fondo = '#333'
     document.cookie = "fondo="+fondo  
    document.body.style.background = fondo
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('day-main');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "whitesmoke";
  }
  function day(){
    var fondo = '#f1f1f1'
  document.cookie = "fondo="+fondo  
    document.body.style.background = fondo
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('day-main');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "black"
  }
  
  
  //Leer la cookie
  
 function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

```html
<button id='white' onclick='day()' value='White'>White</button>
<button id='black' onclick='dark()' value='Dark'>Dark</button>
```

Este cogido no se puede ejecutar aquí por cuestiones de seguridad.  Mas [info aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

---

### Editado

```
//Creas dos funciones que hagan cada uno lo suyo (incluido guardar la cookie)
function Oscura(){...codigo....}

function clara(){..codigo...}

  //Tienes que setear ambas sobre la misma cookie para que
  // se sobrescriba
  document.cookie = "fondo=claro" // O puede ser oscuro. La defines en el botón.


//Recuperas la cookie cuando inicie la pagina. 
//Y ejecutas una u otra función dependiendo del valor de tu cookie.


switch(getCookie('fondo')){
    case: 'claro':
        clara()
        break
    case: 'oscuro':
        oscura()
        break

}
```

Comment: y en el caso de ```document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.remove('dark-bg');
    document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('day-main');
    document.getElementById("post-title-data").style.color = "black"```? aqui use id y class por que no se añadia el color asi que lo force con ``!important``

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: me refiero a como aplica a esa parte tambien, ya que tengo un estilo para el fondo, oto para el contenedor, y otro para un h1 este codigo añade y quita clases en una id espesifica ej ```<h1 id="post-title-data"></h1> <div id="main-cont"></div>```

Comment: Puedes crear las cookies que necesites. Por ejemplo estilo_fondo, estilo_contenedor y estilo_h1.

Comment: osea `var estilo_contenedor = document.getElementById('main-cont').classList.add('dark-bg');`

Comment: Solo lo que tienes entre paréntesis ocupa guardarse en las cookies. Después recuperas las cookies en una variable y la pones dónde debe ir para que aplique el estilo. Estoy modificando la pregunta para poner un ejemplo.